# Runtime of dynamically created functions in Julia

Tags: julia

I'd like to use the modelling toolbox in Julia to model circuits (as in this article https://mtk.sciml.ai/stable/tutorials/acausal_components/). However, in my case I don't know a priori what the circuits will be, so the functions will have to be created dynamically. I will need to simulate multiple circuits, but only simulate each one once. Ideally the total simulation time will be under 5 seconds for each circuit.

Is it feasible timing-wise to use Julia for such a task? It's taking 5-10 seconds to import ModellingToolKit and DifferentialEquations alone each time I run the example code in the link. This seems infeasible if it has to be repeated each time I need to create a new circuit model. It would be a shame not to, as the creation of custom functions seems very simple as opposed to e.g. modelica

Comment: How often do you create models? The typical Julia workflow is to import the needed libraries once, and keep the session open for doing multiple calculations Then the overhead disappears.

Comment: Ok, so to provide more detail - using a genetic algorithm to propose circuits, so easily on the order of 50-100. I'd like to use Julia to generate time-domain simulations for the models generated in Python - is it possible to import the libraries only once using that approach?

Comment: Yes, you can call Python from Julia, or vice versa. The main thing is that you should make sure that Julia is not re-started and that the Julia code and libraries are not re-compiled for each model. Take a look here for calling either way between the languages: https://github.com/cjdoris/PythonCall.jl